# What are the most common issues with data cleaning (e.g. outliers, duplicates)? Who has data sets that need to be prepared for analysis?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data

When preparing data for analysis, I often encountered issues such as outliers, data entries that are logically inconsistent (e.g. age=150/age=-2), duplicates (that are not exactly equal) etc. When integrating data sets from different sources, there might not be a unique identifier oder data entries follow different standards (e.g. US vs. United States), which makes matching hard.

What are the issues you experience most commonly when working with data?

Comment: This question is very broad, probably too broad for a question and answer format. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 5):

There can be numerous instances where data needs to be cleansed and standardised.
To name a few -:

1) Mandatory fields having Null values - This is the greatest source of data loss

Remedy - Going back to the business, Replacing them with the mean.

2)Standardising columns- Like USA, US, America, United States.
Remedy- Using a lookup to change them to one standard value.

3)Date- This is one major issue where a file might have multiple date formats.
Remedy-This can be solved again by using a lookup.

4)Duplicates - This can be easily solved either in excel or in the database. You can even have a stored procedure for this.

5)Outliers- This is a separate thing all together, an outlier is a datapoint which comes from different distribution.I would suggest using the 3-standard deviation rules to mark potential outliers and then using a grub's test to check if they are outliers.

You can find cleansed and uncleansed datasets here  https://www.datazar.com/

I hope this helped you.If you need any further details, feel free to email me at
pramit@datazar.com

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Pramit's answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9478/4293):

- Entities are stored differently: system A stores full name, whereas B stores first name and last name.
- Character set issues: data was exported from system A to B and B cannot interpret characters from A correctly (or the conversion process had errors). This is common when exporting to CSV format.
- Field values in table X point to an index field in table Y, but that record no longer exists (lookup fails)
- Not properly distinguishing NULL and 0 values (or NULL values and empty strings)
- Varying CASING For values that Should HAVE consistent CASing
- End dates before start dates
- Date ranges that are not sequential (have gaps)
- Invalid dates
- Missing values
- Invalid usage of field types, i.e. storing numbers or dates in text fields, strings in a string field have their length prepended (yes, I've seen that)
- Values that are valid in one system but not in another, e.g in a DB/2 database you can store time 24:00 - try that in Oracle or SQL Server.
- Different decimal separators; using thousand separators
- Different languages used for texts

Then there's a whole separate class of the issues coming from databases that are not properly normalized. Some that come to mind:

- Value duplicated in table X looked up from table Y no longer matches with the current value in Y
- Field value Z calculated from fields X and Y does not equal the actual calculation when you re-do it
- Putting `2;12;34;5` in a string field instead of storing those numbers as integers in a detail table